# How to disable Spring's @Scheduled fixedDelay

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am using `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)` to run a function in Spring Boot application.

Now, I want the Scheduler to run on production environment only (should not run on development environment).

If it is `cron`, I can do something like `@Scheduled(cron = "${someProperty}")` and make `someProperty="-"` for development environment.

Is there any similar way for `fixedDelay`?

Comment: @Profile("production") worked for my scenario. I used it at the component level.

Answer (score 1):

You could input a negative value for disabling the field.
However, Spring required exactly one of `fixedDelay`, `cron` or `fixedRate` exists.

I suggest that you use 2 variables for cron and `fixedDeplay` for the wanted effect

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, cron = "") // for enable it
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = -1, cron = "-") // for disable it
```